# Twitter typeahead not showing text only a blank drop down

Tags: json, django, typeahead.js

I am having a problem with my `typeahead`, the suggestion dropdown box comes up while typing however no text are shown. What I did to see if it was just a random dropdown was to type words that I know are in my `json` file and words that are not. Once I type words that are not in my database the dropdown box is removed, so it is actually working without the actual text from the `json` file. Also while typing in the search box, I see within the python console that a query is being made.

Here you can see me typing 'Number theory' that is in my `json`, as you can see the dropdown appears without any text.

[image: Here you can see me typing 'Number theory' that is in my <code>json</code>]

I made sure that my `json` format is correct by using http://jsonlint.com/. Why isn't the text showing in the drop down box?

This is my view:

```
def search_subclasss(request):

    q = request.GET.get('subclass', '')
    sub_classs = SubClasss.objects.filter(subclasss__icontains=q)
    results = []

    for subclasss in sub_classs:

        results.append([subclasss.subclasss, subclasss.subject_id])

    data = json.dumps(results)

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

This is my html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var bestPictures = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('subclasss'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

            remote: {
                url: "{% url 'search_subclasss' %}?subclass=%QUERY",
                //url: '/search_subclasss/?subclass=%QUERY',
                wildcard: '%QUERY'
            }
        });

        $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
            name: 'subclasss',
            display: 'subclasss',
            limit: 10,
            source: bestPictures
        });
    </script>
```

My form is rendered like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="remote">
       {% render_field form_post.subclass %}
    </div>
</div>
```

With form widget:

```
widget = {'subclass': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control typeahead', 'placeholder': 'class/subclass'}),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem by creating a python dictionary `dict_subclasss` after I performed my filter. After that I just append each `dict_subclass` to the `results` array. Now I can send the `json` to the template from the view.

```
def search_subclasss(request):
    q = request.GET.get('subclass', '')
    sub_classs = SubClasss.objects.filter(subclasss__icontains=q)
    results = []

    for subclasss in sub_classs:
        dict_subclass = {
            'subject': subclasss.subject_id,
            'subclasss': subclasss.subclasss,
        }
       results.append(dict_subclass)

    data = json.dumps(results)

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

What do I get from this? Well `twitter-typeahead` is very selective in how it receives its `json` formats.

The above code will give you a `json` like this, which the `JavaScript` `typeahead` can interpret properly:

```
[{"subject": "AGR", "subclasss": "Agroecology"}, {"subject": "AGR", "subclasss": "Agronomy"},...,{"subject": "TR", "subclasss": "Operations research"}, {"subject": "TR", "subclasss": "Mass transit"}]
```

And what I did before was this `results.append([subclasss.subclasss, subclasss.subject_id])` Which gave the `json` result:

```
[["Agroecology", "AGR"], ["Agronomy", "AGR"],...,["Operations research", "TR"], ["Mass transit", "TR"]]
```

While both are correct `json` format the `key` is just as important as the `value`, and is needed to specify which search field that will be displayed and used to perform the query matching.